# Keras: How to use EarlyStopping based on own metric (or similarly: how to add to the log)

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm currently struggling with trying to figure out how to have Keras do an epoch-based Earlystopping based on a specific metric of mine (it's like a slightly edited version of False Positive rate, if you're curious).

To do this, I'm assuming you need to add said metric to the specific log that model.fit creates, which with my admittedly limited knowledge of classes, I'm struggling to follow what I need to edit to make it happen.

I've seen several examples of people creating their own subclasses and generating separate logs, but none that actually add the log that EarlyStopping seems to go off of.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: An easy way would be write `on_epoch_end()` callback and populate an array of your metric. Whenever it matches your criterion, you terminate the training.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with that, but couldn't figure out how to essentially write my own class variable properly. I eventually got it working, though admittedly still struggling to see how it all fits together properly and tracing where the log is saved/extracted to/from. Thanks for your response regardless =).